# Unlimited relationship in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a big trouble in Unlimited relationship in mongodb and Go.

Here is my example diagram:
[image]

From admin user (as root user), I want to create/delete/update sub user (user with low level).

I use username of subusers which are high-level as user_parentid for subusers which are low-level.

And when I delete/update highlevel, I can delete all subuser under this level.

For example:

When I delete user: **bomon1.bmvt@bk.com.vn**, I must delete all sub user under it.

Here is my mongoDB data:

```
{"_id":  {"$oid":"5eb8baa380e33d0f04876615"},"username":"admin@bk.com.vn","password":"123456","first_name":"AdminBK","last_name":"AdminBK","user_email":"admin@bk.com.vn","user_tel":"0907888511","user_type":"ADMIN_COM","user_date":"2020-05-11","user_status":"ACTIVE","user_parentid":"edu@bk.com.vn","com_id":"DHBK","com_department":"BGH","user_code":"DHBK_0001"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5eb8bf1a80e33d0f04876617"},"username":"bmvt@bk.com.vn","password":"123456","first_name":"BMVT_BK","last_name":"BMVT_BK","user_email":"bmvt@bk.com.vn","user_tel":"0907888512","user_type":"USER_COM","user_date":"2020-05-12","user_status":"ACTIVE","user_parentid":"edu@bk.com.vn","com_id":"DHBK","com_department":"BMVT","user_code":"DHBK_0002"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5eb8f6ac30cb8651e0906d80"},"username":"bomon1.bmvt@bk.com.vn","password":"123456","first_name":"BMVT_BOMON1","last_name":"BMVT_BOMON2","user_email":"user_1.bmvt@bk.com.vn","user_tel":"0907888513","user_type":"USER_COM","user_date":"2020-05-12","user_status":"ACTIVE","user_parentid":"bmvt@bk.com.vn","com_id":"DHBK","com_department":"BMVT","user_code":"DHBK_0003"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5eb8f6d430cb8651e0906d81"},"username":"bomon2.bmvt@bk.com.vn","password":"123456","first_name":"BMVT_BOMON2","last_name":"BMVT_BOMON2","user_email":"user_2.bmvt@bk.com.vn","user_tel":"0907888514","user_type":"USER_COM","user_date":"2020-05-12","user_status":"ACTIVE","user_parentid":"bmvt@bk.com.vn","com_id":"DHBK","com_department":"BMVT","user_code":"DHBK_0004"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5eb8f7cd30cb8651e0906d82"},"username":"gv1.bmvt@bk.com.vn","password":"123456","first_name":"GV1","last_name":"GV1","user_email":"gv1.bmvt@bk.com.vn","user_tel":"0907888515","user_type":"USER_COM","user_date":"2020-05-12","user_status":"ACTIVE","user_parentid":"bomon1.bmvt@bk.com.vn","com_id":"DHBK","com_department":"BMVT","user_code":"DHBK_0005"}
 {"_id":{"$oid":"5eb8f7ee30cb8651e0906d83"},"username":"gv2.bmvt@bk.com.vn","password":"123456","first_name":"GV2","last_name":"GV2","user_email":"gv2.bmvt@bk.com.vn","user_tel":"0907888516","user_type":"USER_COM","user_date":"2020-05-12","user_status":"ACTIVE","user_parentid":"bomon1.bmvt@bk.com.vn","com_id":"DHBK","com_department":"BMVT","user_code":"DHBK_0006"}
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/index.html#graphlookup-aggregation)

Comment: Hi sir, I will add my mongoDB database. Could you give me an expamle or query command. Thanks.

Comment: The example diagram is very similar to the 'reportsTo' example in the docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/index.html#graphlookup-aggregation

Comment: How does this relate to Go?

Comment: @Flimzy, I want to implement this in Go, such as update and delete.

Comment: @Joe: how to add condition for this query?

Comment: The language you implement this in has nothing to do with your data model, which is what you seem to be asking about right now. When you have an actual problem implementing this in go, please ask a separate question about that.